# Compilation error after texlive update

Tags: beamer, pstricks, texlive, standalone, preview

I used to make animated pictures using `pstricks` and the `beamer` overlay syntax (eg. using `\only<2>{<some pstricks code>}`) with the `standalone` class.

Here a MWE which did the work:

```
\documentclass[beamer,pstricks,preview=true]{standalone}

\standaloneenv{{pspicture}}

\psset{unit=2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psdot(0,0)
    \only<2>{\psdot(1,1)}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

This MWE does compile with texlive2013 (iso-version) with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`: a pdf with two pages and just the pspictures environment correctly croped.  HOWEVER it does not compile with a fully updated texlive2013 distribution, the conversion from ps to pdf fails with the following message:

```
Error: /typecheck in --div--
Operand stack:

   1   1   0.0   0.0   a   65781.8

Execution stack:

   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   
--nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   
--nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   
1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   
%oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   
--nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   
--nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   4   
--nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--

Dictionary stack:

   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:127/200(L)--   
--dict:173/300(L)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: 2

Current file position is 101382

GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

This code does compile by removing the `preview` package but the result is not what is expected. I also tried to active `preview` with the option of the `standalone` package but this is also without effect.

Does someone know how to resolve this problem, or how to modify the MWE so that it compiles and give the right output ?

Comment: Why do xou need the `standalone` class for the presentation?

Comment: It's not for a presentation, I use this combination to create animated pictures without needing to copy the whole body for each picture. But now that you say it, I may actually not have to use the `standalone` class to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a lot of try and errors, I've couldn't find out why this code no longer works with an updated TexLive distribution. However I've found a workaround.

It seems that somehow the `preview` package and `pstricks` do not come along together anymore. So the workaround is to deactivate the preview option of the `standalone` package. That way there is no compilation errors anymore, but the result is not what is expected. Indeed the `standaloneframe` environment kind of override the directive `\standaloneenv{{pspicture}}` so that the crop is done to the dimensions of the `standaloneframe` and not to the dimensions of the `pspicture`.
Using the `geometry` package allows to set the dimensions of the `standonealoneframe` so that they match the dimensions of the `pspicture` resolves the problem:

```
\documentclass[beamer,pstricks,preview=false]{standalone}

\geometry{paperheight=20cm,paperwidth=20cm,left=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm}

\psset{unit=2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}%
  \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psdot(0,0)
    \only<2>{\psdot(1,1)}
  \end{pspicture}%
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This hack with `\geometry` may not be the best solution.