# PS-Tricks + Beamer Problem

Tags: beamer, pstricks

I have a strange problem with PS-Tricks. I can only create one picture when using beamer. Take this as an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \psline(0,0)(1,1)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \psline(0,0)(1,1)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Only the first frame contains a pstricks graphic, the second one is empty. Pstricks only creates the first graphic and ignores the rest.

Any ideas to this? I use TexLive 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stolen from Herbert's answer [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192649/19356).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\makeatletter
\let\Test@pr@shipout\pr@shipout%% save the original definition
\let\Test@shipout\shipout
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\pr@shipout\Test@pr@shipout%% restore it 
  \let\shipout\Test@shipout
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \psline(0,0)(1,1)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)
  \psline[linecolor=red](0,0)(1,1)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]